# php curl 10 seconds timeout

Tags: php, curl

Code:

```
<?php
$directory = 'http://www.google1.com';  
$returntransfer = true;
$connecttimeout = 10;
$timeout = 10; 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $directory);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returntransfer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $connecttimeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

$execute = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($curl_errno > 0) {
    echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
}
?>
```

I want to wait 10 seconds on browser. After 10 seconds, it will show the error messages on the browser. However, when I refresh my web page, it only load 3 seconds. How should I do in order to load 10 seconds on the browser?

Comment: "I want to wait 10 seconds on browser. " - `sleep(10);` (ahah.)

Comment: If you want simulate the timeout: `$directory = 'http://www.google.com'; ` and add `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 81);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, its simple.

you should use `sleep(10)`;

to wait browser for 10 sec

Answer (score 0):

`http://google1.com` doesn't resolve for me. After the query gets stored locally, the DNS request will timeout immediately no matter what you set `$timeout` to be.