# php curl 10 seconds timeout (part2)

Tags: php, curl

- continue on [php curl 10 seconds timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791894/php-curl-10-seconds-timeout?noredirect=1#comment43993516_27791894)
- code

  ```
  <?php
  $directory = 'http://www.google1.com';  
  $returntransfer = true;
  $connecttimeout = 10;
  timeout = 10; 

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $directory);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returntransfer);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $connecttimeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

  sleep(10); //wait 10 sec on browser

  $execute = curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
  $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  if ($curl_errno > 0) {
      echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
  }
  ?>
  ```
- From the above code, my questions is the following:
  (1) When I use the `sleep()`, it will wait 10 seconds on the web page but the `CURL_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` seems nothing happened? Why?
  (2) How do I know that the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is set?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your former question was looking to wait for 10 secs in a browser. You achieved that. What do you mean by "nothing happened"? It may help switching `$directory = 'http://www.google1.com';` to `$directory = 'http://www.google.com';`

Comment: @HansZ. How about I set the both timeout to 5 seconds?